Analyzing sql query performance issues in mysql
I am new to mysql, I have few questions in regards to query performance tuning. (Note- its version 8.0.32)

I understand we use "explain analyze" to see the execution plan and it shows the exact resource consumption by running the query behind the scene. But still its quite difficult to understand the exact part of the query which is taking time or relating the exact line of the plan to exact predicate of the query. So is there any other option available through which we can see these informations?

And is there any option to mimic or force certain execution path of the query so that it always follows the same without deviating from that. As because we saw change in execution path for same query many times impact the query response time negatively.

We want to track the historical query response time for any query , if there any data dictionary of catalog tables which which can be queried to see when the application query was running fast vs slow in past, and then further dig into it to fix it if needed (for example if its changing execution path in between on some days) ?



I suggest that you post table description some data example and expected result . Add execution plan for that particular query which is slow. All in text format. In that case from an answer you could understand how to use explain to analyze and  optimize the query . Otherwise i think  your question will be closed.


Yeah, none of the EXPLAINs manage to say what should be done.  PROFILE is useless.
USE INDEX, FORCE INDEX, IGNORE INDEX, STRAIGHT_JOIN, and certain settings are the tools for such.  But I strongly advise against leaving such tips in place in production.  "What helps today may make things worse tomorrow".
The SlowLog .  Typically, the one or two "worst" queries are the ones to work on.  Rinse and repeat.  Novices often do not understand the benefit of carefully chosen "composite indexes" and the issues of "sargability".

Post CREATE TABLE and EXPLAIN SELECT in a question on stackoverflow.com with a tags of [mysql] [performance] to get (my) attention for further detail analysis.
